# Android Google Map xml R.id undefined in fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I`m developing an application that uses an activity with navigation drawer. I have two fragments in the drawer one of which is a google map.

In the map fragment class I want to initialize the GoogleMap object to do some things to the map, but in the onCreateView after I initialize the view through inflater, my app doesn't find the id in R class to initialize the google map.

I call the fragment from the activity through:

```html
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainContent, map, Map.class.getSimpleName());
     fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Map.class.getSimpleName());
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

the container xml:

```html
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/background_color" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

layout_fragment_map.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The Map fragment class:

```html
public class Map extends Fragment {
 
 private View view;
 private MapFragment mapFragment;
 private GoogleMap googleMap;
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }
 
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
  if (view != null) {
         ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
         if (parent != null)
             parent.removeView(view);
     }
     try {
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_map, container, false);
     } catch (InflateException e) {
         /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
     }
     
     mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
     
     return view;
 }
```

In the line:

```html
mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

the R.id.map is undefined Eclipse gives "could not resolve type".

Something is missing or my whole concept is faulty?

Thank you and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by modifying the line:

```html
 mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
```

with

```html
mapFragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
```

It is strange because the R.id.googleMap is still undefined but the object gets created correctly.